# Variable said to be immutable even if declared as mutable

Tags: rust, immutability, mutable

I am recreating the arithmetic operations in binary by representing numbers with a vector of booleans. Since the size of each vector can vary, I made a function to match the length of each vector:

```
fn match_lengths(mut bit_vec0: Vec<bool>, mut bit_vec1: Vec<bool>) -> (Vec<bool>, Vec<bool>) {
    {
        let (mut shorter, longer) = if bit_vec0.len() < bit_vec1.len() {
            (&bit_vec0, &bit_vec1)
        } else {
            (&bit_vec1, &bit_vec0)
        };
        let bit_sign = match shorter.last() {
            Some(content) => *content,
            None => false,
        };

        for _ in shorter.len()..longer.len() {
            shorter.push(bit_sign);
        }
    }

    (bit_vec0, bit_vec1)
}
```

I get the error

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow immutable borrowed content `*shorter` as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:15:13
   |
15 |             shorter.push(bit_sign); // Error here
   |             ^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
```

Even though I declared it with the `mut` specifier.

Comment: The next time you have an error, I suggest using your favorite search engine to search for the error text. Many times, an existing Stack Overflow question will be the top result (especially if you limit your search to this domain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `shorter` is a *reference*, more precisely a `&Vec<bool>`, which means it refers to a `Vec<bool>` which it is not allowed to mutate<sup>1</sup>.

Declaring the variable as `mut shorter` only makes the `shorter` variable mutable, allowing you to e.g. use `shorter = ...` assignment to make it refer to a different `Vec<bool>`. Regardless of the variable's mutability, a shared reference of type `&Vec<bool>` is not allowed to mutate the object it refers to.

What you need to do is make a mutable reference of type `&mut Vec<bool>`, using `&mut bit_vec0` and `&mut bit_vec1`. This change makes the code compile, and at that point `shorter` no longer needs to be `mut`.

Finally, and this is unrelated to the question, `match_lengths` accepts `bit_vec0` and `bit_vec1` by value, modifies them, and returns them. Although that certainly works, it is more idiomatic to accept mutable references. Such an approach is more ergonomic for the caller, and more clearly signals the fact that the function doesn't really "return" anything, it really modifies existing objects.

With those modifications, the function looks like this:

```
fn match_lengths(bit_vec0: &mut Vec<bool>, bit_vec1: &mut Vec<bool>) {
    let (shorter, longer) = if bit_vec0.len() < bit_vec1.len() {
        (bit_vec0, bit_vec1)
    } else {
        (bit_vec1, bit_vec0)
    };
    let bit_sign = match shorter.last() {
        Some(content) => *content,
        None => false,
    };
    for _ in shorter.len()..longer.len() {
        shorter.push(bit_sign);
    }
}
```

<sup>1</sup>
This sounds much like C++'s `const`, but the guarantee in Rust is even stronger than that of `const`: not only is a shared (non-`mut`) reference not allowed to mutate the object it refers to, but neither is anyone else! Rust's compiler and runtime prevent creation of a `mut` reference to an object while any shared references to that object exist.